# Enlarge range input

Tags: html, css, range

I want to have a range input with a bigger cursor and bar (not longer).

```html
<input id="speed" type="range" min="10" max="80" />
```

How should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you want to use the built in range input (rather than a custom input) there are a number of browser specific styles you can use: https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean a custom input? Is it simpler to customize an input in order to make it look like a range input? If so, do you have a code snippet?

Comment: you can target the range inside input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by bigger you just mean a bigger area to grab and drag, so this should work:

```css
#range {
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.3); /* Or however big you want it */
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="range">
```

It's sort of hacky, but it works.

Comment: How is it hacky? It's exactly what I want.

Comment: Well, because there may be side effects that you'd have to watch out for. Mostly overlapping elements because the transform isn't in the flow

Answer (score 1):

As of end 2018, there is no cross browser way to do this, however there are ways to get this done in most browsers.

- Firefox: `::-moz-range-thumb` and `::-moz-range-track`.
- Chrome:  `::-webkit-slider-thumb` and `::-webkit-slider-runnable-track`.
- Edge: `::-ms-thumb` and  `::-ms-track`.
- Safari: not sure.

For a more complete guide and examples how to use those pseudo elements checkout [this CSS tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/)